# Symfony2 Assetic vs Grunt - what should I use?

Tags: symfony, gruntjs, assetic

What are the pros and cons of ussing Assetic vs Grunt in my project? Which one is "better"? I heard that dealing with Assetic is a lot of pain, for me it looks ok, but I never used it that much. I found this http://konradpodgorski.com/blog/2014/06/23/better-way-to-work-with-assets-in-symfony-2/ and Grunt looks pretty good. I could try both myself but I'm in the middle of fixing a project and I need to choose some technology ASAP, so I need tldr; version of advantages and disadvantages of using either technology.

Answer (score 1):

never used grunt together with symfony2, but i promised to myself that i will do it the next time.

building and watching for changes including possibly livereload are definitly the pro's for grunt! another pro for grunt is that there are thousands of plugins available, which could potentially do stuff like image-minification, uncss and so on. i don't think there is an easy way to do this with assetic.

overall it possibly depends on your usecase. if you simply just want to concatenate files it is probably easier to use assetic. otherwise i would definitly choose grunt (i'm confident in using grunt, just because i used it a lot)

Answer (score 1):

Assetic is PHP so you can manipulate it at run time. Bundles can extend your templates and add stylessheets etc automatically.

On the other hand grunt is JavaScript and cant be integrated into your program at run-time but it supports a wider array of tools and is easier to configure.